# How to find the source code of a package in my computer?

Tags: subfloats, documentation

Time and again I am in the need of figuring out the arguments/options of a package, and more often than not I get very frustrated with the results I get online. Even worse, sometimes I get confused because a command actually belongs to a package with a completely different name. Since I'm noticing this is a recurrent problem (which honestly I just have with LaTeX), I'd like to instead see the actual code in my installation and try to figure it out myself.

For instance, I am currently trying to figure out the options that `\subfloat` accepts, but googling `\subfloat` documentation lead me to [some](ftp://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/subfig.pdf) [pdfs](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/subfloat/subfloat.pdf) that are actually of little help. So I'd like to instead look at the source code of `\subfloat`. How can I do that? I am using Miktex and WinEdt.

Thanks,
Jorge.

Comment: It's always best to start with the proper documentation before delving into code. So perhaps start here: [How to find the documentation for a package?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/380019) which shows you various ways to get the actual documentation for a package.

Comment: You probably want the manual, rather than the source code. For instance, looking in the source code would reveal that `\subfloat` actually has *no* argument (the arguments are passed to auxiliary macros).

Comment: You can show in the log-file (you normally get it with ctrl+l in winedt). There the pathes to all files are noted. To get documentation use texdoc (see "latex doc" in the help menu of winedt).

Comment: Have a look at `Table 2` from the subfig documentation, there is a nice list which arguments/options are possible: https://i.stack.imgur.com/08ZNb.png

Comment: @AlanMunn: Yes, I tried those approaches before posting (texdoc, CTAN, manual), but they were of no help (in the end, they forward to the pdfs I mentioned).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: thanks, that's exactly what I was needing! I guess the follow-up question is: "how to know in which package a command is defined? (like, how to know that \subfloat is defined in subfig?)

Comment: It depends on whether you loaded in admin (`C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\subfig\subfig.sty`) or user (`C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\subfig\subfig.sty`).

Comment: @samcarter: thanks, that answers the question at hand indeed!

Comment: @JohnKormylo: according to WinEdt I use the latter... are there any differences between those two?

Comment: It's a security issue.  You need admin status to update Program Files.  And I can never find the manual in Roaming.

Comment: @dontpanic Concerning the question how to find out in which package a command is defined: Texstudio has a nice feature for this, right click on a command and you'll get a menu which tells you the name an the package and allows you to directly open the documentation https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaTQZ.png (works for many but not all packages)

Comment: ``kpsewhich packagename.dtx``

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard way to display the manual of a package or class, say `pkg.sty` (or `class.cls`), is at the terminal (where > stands for your particular terminal prompt):

```
> texdoc pkg
```

Some package manuals show the package code. If that doesn't show the information you are after then, also at the terminal input:

```
> kpsewhich pkg.sty
```

which will tell you where the file `pkg.sty` is located on your system and you can then look at that in all its glory.

Comment: On a Mac, you can use `open \`kpsewhich pkg.sty\`` and it will open with your preferred editor for `.sty` files. On Linux you can use `xdg-open` instead of `open`. Perhaps a similar functionality exists in the Windows command line too.